# Invariance principle for stability in the sense of Lyapunov

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, differential-equations

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle's_invariance_principle) this article about the invariance principle and article states that

> The general result was independently discovered by J.P. LaSalle (then
>   at RIAS) and N.N. Krasovskii, who published in 1960 and 1959
>   respectively. While LaSalle was the first author in the West to
>   publish the general theorem in 1960, a special case of the theorem was
>   in communicated in 1952 by Barbashin and Krasovskii, followed by a
>   publication of the general result in 1959 by Krasovskii.

Hence, I am wondering if this claim is correct (references please I couldn't find the reference form 1959).

Answer (score 1):

MR0106313 Krasovskiĭ, N. N. {\cyr Nekotorye zadachi teorii ustoĭchivosti dvizheniya.} (Russian) [Certain problems in the theory of stability of motion] Gosudarstv. Izdat. Fiz.-Mat. Lit., Moscow 1959 211 pp.

MR0052616 Barbašin, E. A.; Krasovskiĭ, N. N. On stability of motion in the large. (Russian) Doklady Akad. Nauk SSSR (N.S.) 86, (1952). 453-456.